# Javascript ES6 Map an array of objects into Set or filter out by distinct property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

I have an object array with property of name and age, I would like to filter out a collection of distinct age among the array, so I can do something like

```
function distinctAges() {
    const guests = [
          {name: 'Kiley', age: 24}, 
          {name: 'Tom', age: 36}, 
          {name: 'Jason', age: 67},
          {name: 'Mike', age: 24},
          ...];

    let ageSet = new Set();
    guests.foreach(g => ageSet.add(g.age));
    return ageSet;
}
```

Is there anyway not using the `Set` datatype, like a `Distinct` operation? Of if using the `Set`, is there anyway to write the conversion in one line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sets are the JS current way of getting an array of distinct values. You can map an array of objects to an array of values, create a Set, and then spread back to an array:

```js
const distinctBy = (prop, arr) => [...new Set(arr.map(o => o[prop]))]

const guests = [{"name":"Kiley","age":24},{"name":"Tom","age":36},{"name":"Jason","age":67},{"name":"Mike","age":24}]

const result = distinctBy('age', guests)

console.log(result)
```

To make this more generic, you can replace the `prop` with a predicate function:

```js
const distinctBy = (predicate, arr) => [...new Set(arr.map(predicate))]

const guests = [{"name":"Kiley","age":24},{"name":"Tom","age":36},{"name":"Jason","age":67},{"name":"Mike","age":24}]

const result = distinctBy(o => o.age, guests)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I dislike using magic strings in function calls like this as it's prone to errors. Any subsequent changes to the `guests` object (such as changing 'age' to 'guestAge' for example) would not raise any compilation errors.

Comment: @DanAtkinson - see updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Actually you also may just use .reduce

```js
      const guests = [
          {name: 'Kiley', age: 24}, 
          {name: 'Tom', age: 36}, 
          {name: 'Jason', age: 67},
          {name: 'Mike', age: 24}]
      
    console.log(guests.reduce((acc, rec) => acc.includes(rec.age) ? acc : [...acc, rec.age], []))
```

or with Set in one line:

```js
      const guests = [
          {name: 'Kiley', age: 24}, 
          {name: 'Tom', age: 36}, 
          {name: 'Jason', age: 67},
          {name: 'Mike', age: 24}]
          
console.log([...new Set(guests.map(it => it.age))])
```

Comment: I think your second example is probably the right approach for most people. It's succinct and strongly typed, even if it's not in a re-usable function. I considered the accepted answer but found that using magic strings was too problematic.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this -- the question is "how to determine uniqueness", which is often problem-domain dependent.

One trick I frequently use if I can't use Set is to collide property names in a junk object, because this tends to be quite fast for reasonable sized-sets in JavaScript --

```
let seen={};
let ageList=guests.filter((obj) => { 
  let ret = !seen[obj.age];
  seen[obj.age] = true; 
  return ret;
}).map((obj) => obj.age);
console.log(ageList);
```

This code sets a property in `seen` which has the same name as your age during the filter function.  If it was unset, it returns true, so that that record will be part of the filtered array.  Then I apply a map function which maps guest objects to ages.  The result is an array which contains all of the unique ages.

One optimization might be to use a spare Array instead of an Object to determine uniqueness, knowing (assuming) that all ages are numbers and they tend to be quite small -- simply change `seen={}` to `seen=[]` in the example above.

Of course, Knuth would point out that premature optimization is the root of all evil -- and I would point out that if you care about optimization you also need to measure....